# ImportError: cannot dynamically load executable

Tags: python

In python/3.6.5 I receive an ImportError with the message: cannot dynamically load executable.

I try to run this code on a remote server where I set up the following environment to install the python module: gcc/9.1.0 python/3.6.5

The gnu_comp is needed since the python module is wrapped around some fortran and cpython code. The problem arises when I try to load the module as:

```
from fastell4py import fastell4py
```

which raises the error:

```
ImportError: .../lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastell4py-0.1.0-py3.6-linux-
x86_64.egg/fastell4py/_fastell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
cannot dynamically load executable
```

On my local machine I manage to import the module and use it without any problems. The compilers are the same on my local and remote machine (gcc/9.1.0), and the python version differs since on my local machine I use python/3.7.4.

Does anyone have an idea about the origin of the error and how to solve it?

The package is available at: https://github.com/sibirrer/fastell4py

Comment: You might want to list out (or at least summarise) the steps you followed on their bug tracker to avoid repeating them here.

Comment: @Mokubai : Could you clarify for me what you mean with "their bug tracker".

Comment: This issue you raised here https://github.com/sibirrer/fastell4py/issues/1.

Comment: @Mokubai : The issure I raised on their github repo is still open because they did not have any working suggestions. Whatever they suggestion was does not work. The github repo also does not contain any step-by-step list of known bugs and how to solve them, not in the README.md or anywhere else.